# MySQL design and best design practices

Tags: mysql, database-design, best-practices

I am designing my first database for a mobile application, which is also planned to be developed into a web application. The photo shows the part responsible for user authentication and information about him and his current session, etc. I would like to hear from someone with experience what they think about this project, what it is worth changing and why, what practices to follow to make the database effective and safe, I want to understand if I am thinking in the right direction. Thank you in advance for any comments. I would be grateful for your understanding.

I don't know if it matters, but the potential number of users is about 30.000, in the best case about 200.000.

[image]

Comment: _"what it is worth changing and why..."_ **The developer.** It's hard to avoid this sounding cruel or disrespectful, but honestly — would _you_ trust a mobile app or website if the authentication were developed by someone who admits it's their first database?

Comment: If you don't have any specific comments or suggestions then why the hell are you talking, I don't think you'll get a specific answer on this forum anymore. A person tries to learn something new and get opinions on whether it is going well, and all he gets is useless comments about why he is doing it at all. I have experience with backend and authentication, but no experience with database design..

Comment: I'm creating my personal project from scratch, from frontend to backend and databases myself, to learn even more, but since I haven't dealt strictly with databases yet and I always try to stick to good techniques in a given field, that's where the question comes from..

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to not do it at all but buy a 3rd party SaaS option such as Auth0 (no affiliation).

You get the benefit of being able to federate with corporate identity providers (if that's your market) or Google, FB etc. if not.

It's easier and not worth the effort involved when you inevitably introduce a security problem with your home grown solution.

Comment: I absolutely agree with you, unfortunately when it comes to this particular application, the login method cannot be through an intermediary, and data privacy is crucial, therefore there cannot be intermediate data administrators.